# How do you access an ng-repeat item in a directive's scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How do you set the scope value for something like this:

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <my-element ng-repeat="p in people" person='p'></my-element>
</div>
```

```javascript
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('myElement', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>{{ name }}</div> <div>{{ age }}</div>'
    }
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.people = [{ name: 'Mike', age: 20 },{name: 'Peter', age: 22 }];
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If by "set the scope value" you mean have the template work, then

```
template: '<div>{{ p.name }}</div> <div>{{ p.age }}</div>'
```

Since each iteration of ng-repeat creates a new child scope, `p` is defined on that scope.  Since your directive is not creating an isolate scope, you don't need attribute `person`, so this works with the above:

```
<my-element ng-repeat="p in people"></my-element>
```

If you want an isolate scope, use

```
<my-element ng-repeat="p in people" person='p'></my-element>
```

and

```
return {
   restrict: 'E',
   scope: {
       person: '='
   },
   template: '<div>{{ person.name }}</div> <div>{{ person.age }}</div>'
}
```

Comment: is this form `ng-repeat="p in people" person='p'` still valid. I don't see it mentioned in the docs and give error for me. thanks

Comment: The first form is brittle, because it relies on the loop variable name, which is chosen by the user of the directive... The second form works well, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

I like to use '@' when defining the directive scope. This enables the directive isolated scope to access p, for example in link:

```
return {
   scope: '@',
   link: function(scope) {
       console.log(scope.p); //It can now be accessed because of '@'
   }
}
```

Comment: in your example it can be accessed without '@' too

Answer (score 3):

you do not need to create an isolated scope in the directive.
ng repeat will do this automatically for you.
so just remove:

in the directive:

```
scope: {
   person: '='
},
```

and in the ng repeat html markup:

```
person='p'
```

in your directive you will be able to access something like

```
$scope.p.personAttribute
```

like mentioned in the explanation here:
[angularjs-pass-instance-of-each-ng-repeat-in-html-to-directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618621/angularjs-pass-instance-of-each-ng-repeat-in-html-to-directive/16619083#16619083)