# AngularJs pass instance of each ng-repeat in HTML to directive

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm thinking this should be simple but I'm missing something. How can I pass a `flowObj` in my `ng-repeat` below to my directive? I want to pass it to my directive then, on click, use that `FlowObj`, then apply some logic. I tried using the commented code in my directive

```
scope: { 
    test:"@" 
}
```

But it seems to screw up my CSS.

HTML:

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="center_outer">
         <div id="center_inner" ng-controller="CtrlPageFlow">
            <div flowclick class="cflow" ng-repeat="flowObj in flows">
               {{flowObj.name}}
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here is my directive

```
angular.module('directives', ['opsimut']).directive('flowclick', function() {
    return {   
        /* 
        scope: {
            test:"@"   // set the attribute name on the directive's scope
        },
        */
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            elem.bind('click', function(scope) {
                debugger;
                alert(scope.flowObj);
                //scope.name += '!';
                //scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

SOLUTION BASED ON ANSWER:

```js
angular.module('directives', ['opsimut']).
directive('flowclick', function() {
  return {
    link: function(e, elem, attr) {
      // scope is the directive's scope,
      // elem is a jquery lite (or jquery full) object for the directive root element.
      // attr is a dictionary of attributes on the directive element.
      elem.bind('click', function(e1) {
        debugger;
        alert(e.flowObj);
      }, e);
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** Remove the whole `scope` property from your directive and everything should work as expected.

**ALSO:**
You'll need to rename the `scope` argument from this line:

```
elem.bind('click', function(scope) {
```

to something like:

```
elem.bind('click', function(e) {
```

because you are overwriting access to `scope` in your event handler by using the same name.

**EXPLANATION:**

The `ng-repeat` directive causes each of its clones to have their own new scope. Since directives on an element share scope by default, any other directives placed alongside the `ng-repeat` share its scope and have access to the current iteration's `$scope` variables. In other words, your custom directive already shares scope with `ng-repeat` and has access to `flowObj` by default.

The reason it didn't work when specifying a `scope` property on your custom directive is that this caused the directive to have its own isolate scope which did not share with `ng-repeat` and so you did not have access to variables on the clones' scopes.