# How to access parent scope in directive on nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Simple question but i unable to find why in this template, the format-property directive can not access  to device?

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="device in devices">
        <format-property ng-repeat="property in properties"></format-property>
    </tr>
</table>
```

althought with this template it works:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="device in devices">
        <td ng-repeat="property in properties">
            <format-property></format-property>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I tried `scope.device` and `scope.$parent.device` without success.
Here my [**demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/AioxHWDUZ4Ut0oPdlny2?p=preview)

**Edit**

I can access to `property` but not to `device`. Unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657591/how-do-you-access-an-ng-repeat-item-in-a-directives-scope), i have a nested ng-repeat

Here a new [**demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/MiwtM1c0mcXOdgGkfbA0?p=preview) with an isolated scope

Comment: From your demo, it looks like you are recreating a controller and a $scope and trying to call it. You need to just pass the controller handling the device and property ng-repeats.

Comment: No, the scope is the local scope (the scope of ng-repeat). I can access to `property` from the directive

Comment: 2 nd one is working fine man.

Comment: yes but it is not that i want!

Comment: What u want exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you access an ng-repeat item in a directive's scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657591/how-do-you-access-an-ng-repeat-item-in-a-directives-scope)

Comment: @Groben: I have edited my question

Comment: Can you show us the definition of format property directive ?

Comment: @Gorben: you can see the new demo i added

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/GCbwMMNvxnbHEIZwr5J4?p=preview

Comment: More infos: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623698/directive-isolate-scope-with-ng-repeat-scope-in-angularjs

Comment: @Groben: this doesn't work. only one device is displayed

Answer (score 0):

see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AIHwQfk0k3ZqCVFxD5H4?p=preview)

I think you must add `td` inside `tr` or you can use `div`.

Also you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754889/angular-directive-does-not-evaluate-inside-ng-repeat) link for more details.